# Configure Git hosting on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, virtual-machine, git-extensions

**Hi,
 i am trying to configure git, on my Ubuntu (virtual machine). as instructed this tutorial**

http://www.guztech.nl/wordpress/index.php/2010/02/setting-up-a-git-server-in-ubuntu-with-gitosis-and-using-gitextensions-on-windows/

When i try to clone repository on Windows Host with GitExtension i get FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out ...

I suppose the problem is my connection string git@IP:gitosis-admin.git . What is the Git Port number ? i should forward it to my Ubuntu Virtual machine. But then what would the connection string look like ? git@IP:3390:gitosis-admin.git ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you don't specify a protocol and follow the server name with a colon (and then the repository), Git uses ssh over port 22. See "GIT URLS" at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Comment: Now i get this ... The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is. I used this command to add ssh key to server .. sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/myuser_1.pub .. as is described in tutorial. I will just kill my self because of this git conf. :/

Comment: What client are you using for SSH on the windows machine? You may need to open an ssh connection manually and approve the 'unknown' server being added to the list of known hosts.

Comment: Putty. I was using putty before .. for a long time, but always putting in user name and password. Today i even try to do Putty connection with ssh key .. folowing this tut. http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty ... When i had to put my Public Key in authorized_keys, i couldn't find this file in ~/.ssh/ so i created it (sudo gedit authorized_keys). Still no success. This tutorial is also very old. There is also know_host file .. i pasted there as well .. to try ..

Comment: Did you do step #9 in the tutorial you linked in your original post?

Comment: I managed to Putty conect using SSH key. Seems there was problem with reading authorized_keys file in $HOME/.ssh/ so i created a new one in /etc/$username/authorized_keys and change file path in sshd_config AuthorizedKeysFile .. now i will go again throe first tutorial ..

Comment: I did came over the section where you clone gitosit-admin.git (my path was git@yourserverip:repository/gitosis-admin.git - and not just IP:gitosis-admin.git) .. but creating new repository is not described well. Could you please answer me on this one ? 1.Where do i create new folder called for example "MyProject" ? on clien computer anywhere I want ? 2.Setting up Repositories .. i was changing it in folder on client site where I Cloned repository gitosis-admin then Pushed back on server. Is this correct ? 3. Can repository name or writable be = "repoistory-name" ? Thank you